# MOD operator in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an invalid number exception. How do you use `MOD` in `WHERE` clause? I am wanting to update even or odd rows based on ID.

```
update employee  set respstr1 = 'EP' where mid = 7246 and (mod(id/2) = 1)
```

Comment: How about using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) instead of the `id`? I doubt that it is always guaranteed that the ID is consecutive.

Comment: First, `mod` takes two arguments-- 'mod(id,2) = 1`.  But the error you're getting implies that one (or more) of the columns that you are treating as numeric actually have some non-numeric characters.  What are the data types of the columns involved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct syntax for mod is

```
mod(id,2)
```

Comment: [This is the documentation of the `MOD()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
update employee  set respstr1 = 'EP' where mid = 7246 and (mod(id,2) = 1)
```

For more details please refer to the link below
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm